# In SSMS, editing a table, can column names be sorted alphabetically?

Tags: ssms

SSMS Sorts column names alphabetically in all its dialogs - when choosing columns for indexes, relationships, etc. However, when editing ("Designing") a table, the columns are listed in the order in which they were added to the table, which seems weird and inconsistent.

So is there a way to force sorting alphabetically in the table Design view?

Comment: I assume the OP wanted a way to sort it when viewing the table design. That is something I would want to do as it makes finding a column easier.

Answer (score 0):

No, and you don't really want to do this either.  The order in which the table designer presents the columns is the order used to create or modify the table schema.  Changing this can quite easily break code elsewhere in the database.  Granted it's best practice to write code that is impervious to these types of schema changes, but it still happens all the time.